# How possible data pre processing possible with python for Klipfolio

Tags: python, analysis, klipfolio

I am not sure exactly right place to ask but I need any single infrmation about it.

I am going to create a dashboard with `Klipfolio` and I want to make data pre processing with Python and integrate in klipfolio but unfortunately Klipfoli does not have any specific place to do it.

Is anyone used Klipfolio, data pre processing with Python for Klipfolio.

Answer (score 0):

While Klipfolio does not have any Python integrations, [Klipfolio does connect to various types of SQL databases](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547018-How-do-I-create-an-SQL-database-data-source-). One work around is to dump your processed data from Python into a SQL database and then connect that SQL database with Klipfolio to make data sources to build the visualization.

Answer (score -1):

You can either directly connect to the database, or if you are running python on a server, you can user "Rest/URL" method in Klipfolio to directly connect to your python code and integrate the output into your dashboard.